# How to create Local Repository in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, repository, data-cd

I want to try to use an Ubuntu DVD ISO as a local Repository.

I have tried the following:

1. Mount the ISO; for example in `/mnt/localRepo`
2. In the `/etc/apt/source.list` I put the the following string:

   ```
   deb file:/mnt/localRepo trusty main restricted
   ```

It does not work; could you tell me what I've missed?

I do not want to mirror the repo.

Comment: Should it be `file://` ?

Comment: i will try.....

Answer (score 1):

To add an ISO image as a software source in Ubuntu or Debian based distributions:

`mkdir /media/mountpoint`
`mount -t iso9660 -o loop  /path/to/iso.iso /media/mountpoint`

Then add `deb file:///media/mountpoint distro main contrib` to `/etc/sources.list`.

Refresh the repositories `apt-get update`.

Done.